# How do I export a LibreOffice Base database table with very small numbers? (... using scientific notation?)

Tags: libreoffice-base

https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Importing_and_Exporting_Data_in_Base
tells me to export by copy and pasting into LibreOffice Calc.
This works in general. But my numbers in the database are very small and best expressed in "scientific notation". When I copy and paste my table to Calc nearly all of them become 0.0. While in the database they are 0.0000002.

Where can I change the accuracy of the data copied to clipboard? Or set it to be in "scientific notation"(2.23413E-08)

If I can't get my numbers in the exact representation back into a .csv file it does not make sense to store them in a database at all.

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice Calc (tested with 5.2.3.3) Ctrl+Shift+F4 opens a pane of registered data bases. From there one can drag and drop tables, queries or views into the spreadsheet. The numbers are then preserved.

If the desired database is not yet registered go to Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Base -> Databases -> New ... and follow the wizard.

From: https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=18511